# Language error prevents me of creating folders at Desktop

Tags: 12.04, language-support

My issue is the following:

When I created my user, I decided switching to English instead of Spanish wich was the original language installed, so now when I logged in Ubuntu notified me that if I wanted to replace the old spanish names from the folders, to english, I acepted..

Now when I try to create a folder in Desktop, it pops up an error saying that is "Unable to copy because there's an "Error when getting information for file '/home/****/Escritorio': No such file or directory, is making reference to the old spanish desktop name.

How do I change this route?

Do you think this is affecting the wallpaper that appears at the login screen? Cause it doesn't appear anymore.

Thanks, for your attention.

Regards.

Answer (score 1):

It sounds like when the system changed the names of the folders, it didn't update the links to the old folders. This *would* explain the problem with your desktop.

All I can recommend at the moment is going to each folder, right clicking and selecting "make link", then renaming the link to the old, spanish name for the folder. It's not an ideal solution but it's all I know of.

Comment: Yes, that should do the trick, but I left the desktop name as "Escritorio" and works fine, thanks.